# Bound $T$ asymptotically tight | Recursive trees

Tags: asymptotics, runtime-analysis, recursion, lower-bounds, upper-bound

> Let $\alpha \in (0, 1),\space l \geq 2$ and $T: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^+$ such that, 
> $T(n) = \begin{cases} n^l + T(\alpha n) + T((1-\alpha)n) &  : n > 1  \\1 : n=1 \end{cases}$ 
> Bound $T$ asymptotically tight.

So I understand that I need to split into cases, the first one is where $\alpha < \frac{1}{2}$ and $\alpha \geq \frac{1}{2}$. 
However, I struggle to bound $T$ tightly at each case (I only know how to bound it from one side). 
I'd like to understand the general idea\strategy in situations like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can directly approach this problem using the recurrence tree method. Let us now denote $1-\alpha$ as $\beta$ for notational clarity. For any constant $l\ge2$ we have, $\alpha^l+\beta^l < 1$.

$T(n)$ ----------------------- work = $n^l=n^l(\alpha^l+\beta^l)^0$

/                \

$T(\alpha n)$                 $T(\beta n)$ ------------ work = $(\alpha n)^l+(\beta n)^l=n^l(\alpha^l+\beta^l)$

/          \                 /          \

$T(\alpha^2 n)$ $T(\alpha\beta n)$ $T(\alpha\beta n)$ $T(\beta^2 n)$ --- work = $\small(\alpha^2 n)^l+(\alpha\beta n)^l+(\alpha\beta n)^l+(\beta^2 n)^l=n^l(\alpha^l+\beta^l)^2$

$\vdots$             $\vdots$              $\vdots$             $\vdots$

---

Thus, $T(n) \le \sum\limits_{i=0}^{\log_{1/\max(\alpha,\beta)} n}n^l(\alpha^l+\beta^l)^i \le \sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} n^l(\alpha^l+\beta^l)^i = \frac{n^l}{1-(\alpha^l+\beta^l)} = O(n^l)$

Similarly, $T(n) \ge \sum\limits_{i=0}^{\log_{1/\min(\alpha,\beta)} n}n^l(\alpha^l+\beta^l)^i \ge n^l = \Omega(n^l)$

Therefore, $T(n) = \Theta(n^l)$

PS: One can derive the tight expressions for both the GP series, but the amsymptotic bounds remain the same, so I have opted for very loose bounds.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Akra-Bazzi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method) method we have that
$
\alpha^p + (1-\alpha)^p = 1
$
for $p=1$, and that:
$$
\int_1^n \frac{x^l}{x^{p+1}} \, \text{d}x =
\int_1^n x^{l-2} \, \text{d}x= \frac{x^{l-1}}{l-1} \,\bigg|_{x=1}^{n} = \Theta(n^{l-1}).
$$

Hence:
$$
T(n) = \Theta\Big( n^p \cdot \big(1 + \int_1^n \frac{x^l}{x^{p+1}} \, \text{d}x ) \Big) = \Theta\big( n \cdot (1 + n^{l-1}) \big) = \Theta(n^l).
$$